# Error ':expo-permissions:debugCompileClasspath': recyclerview-1.0.0.jar not found

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I'm having issues with `react-native run android`. Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()        
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2"
            name 'Google'
        }
         maven {
            url "D:/maven"
            name 'LocalRepo'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.lint/lint-gradle-ap"
            name 'lint'
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle fSiles
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://mvnrepository.com/"
            name 'lint'
        }

        mavenLocal()
         maven {
            url "D:/maven"
            name 'LocalRepo'
        }

    }

}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-permissions:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':expo-permissions:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find recyclerview-1.0.0.jar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0).  
     Searched in the following locations:   
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/recyclerview/recyclerview/1.0.0/recyclerview-1.0.0.jar
```

The URL provided returns 404. I've tried it with three different VPNs and four different proxies. I don't know what I should do. It's not even looking n my other repositories. And I can't find a trace of this file on the internet. I found it on a Github repo, but I don't now where to put it.

What could be wrong? I have the latest version of expo, react and react-native.